# JQuery How to get current input type?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, keyboard

I use they keyboard from [[1]](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-keyboard-with-css-and-jquery--net-5774). Unfortunatetly it works only with input types. But I want to run them as well on textareas. However, the current code is not able to do this. The standard code starts the keyboard with the following command:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').mlKeyboard();
});
```

Now I want to extend the code that if, I click into an input text it should show the keyboard and if I click into a textarea it should show the keyboard.

I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').mlKeyboard();
    $('textarea').mlKeyboard();
});
```

But then the keyboard is shown several times. Therefore I want to have an if else command to select which input element has been chosen. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input, textarea').mlKeyboard();
});
```